# Statsmodels: How can I select different confidence intervals for regressions

Tags: regression, statsmodels, confidence-interval

I want to run a regression with 99% confidence interval instead of the default 95% using statsmodels.

I looked at the documentation if there is an argument in the fit() method but I didn't notice something. I tried also the conf_int method but I am confused from the output.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\TestData.xlsx')
df['LogBalance'] = df['Balance'].map(lambda x: math.log(x))
est = sm.ols(formula= 'LogBalance ~ N + Rate',       
    data=df).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
print(est.summary())
print(est.conf_int(alpha=0.01, cols=None))
```

Since I am new in Python can you tell me if and how can I perform a regression in statsmodels with adjusted confidence intervals if possible in the initial regression output?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it is useful for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the confidence interval in `.summary()` [directly](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.summary.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.summary) Please consider the following example:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import seaborn as sns

# load a sample dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# run model
formula = 'tip ~ size + total_bill'
results = smf.ols(formula=formula, data=df).fit()
```

```py
# use 95 % CI (default setting)
print(results.summary())
```

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    tip   R-squared:                       0.468
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.463
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     105.9
Date:                Fri, 21 Jun 2019   Prob (F-statistic):           9.67e-34
Time:                        21:42:09   Log-Likelihood:                -347.99
No. Observations:                 244   AIC:                             702.0
Df Residuals:                     241   BIC:                             712.5
Df Model:                           2                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      0.6689      0.194      3.455      0.001       0.288       1.050
size           0.1926      0.085      2.258      0.025       0.025       0.361
total_bill     0.0927      0.009     10.172      0.000       0.075       0.111
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       24.753   Durbin-Watson:                   2.100
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               46.169
Skew:                           0.545   Prob(JB):                     9.43e-11
Kurtosis:                       4.831   Cond. No.                         67.6
==============================================================================
```

```py
# use 99 % CI
print(results.summary(alpha=0.01))
```

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    tip   R-squared:                       0.468
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.463
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     105.9
Date:                Fri, 21 Jun 2019   Prob (F-statistic):           9.67e-34
Time:                        21:45:57   Log-Likelihood:                -347.99
No. Observations:                 244   AIC:                             702.0
Df Residuals:                     241   BIC:                             712.5
Df Model:                           2                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.005      0.995]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      0.6689      0.194      3.455      0.001       0.166       1.172
size           0.1926      0.085      2.258      0.025      -0.029       0.414
total_bill     0.0927      0.009     10.172      0.000       0.069       0.116
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       24.753   Durbin-Watson:                   2.100
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               46.169
Skew:                           0.545   Prob(JB):                     9.43e-11
Kurtosis:                       4.831   Cond. No.                         67.6
==============================================================================
```